# Redirect /category/item/id-title.html to /category/title using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

If I have the following old links: `example.com/category/item/id-tile.html`

how can I redirect them to `example.com/category/title`

Category changes based on category, item is static, id and title change also. I tried to figure a way through `.htaccess`, but I don't know how do deal with the `id-title` thing.

Comment: Please add your current attempt to the question.

Comment: We do not know your setup, but typically an ID is a required argument to a request, typically used to fetch some data set from a database. The rewriting module cannot somehow _guess_ such an ID. And querying by the title is much less effective, _typically_ ... So are you really sure you want to strip that ID from the URLs?

Comment: I have a website that was moved from Joomla to Wordpress. Joomla, through K2 addon was doing this weird links category/item/id-title.html

Comment: Is there anything else in your .htaccess file other than the standard WordPress front controller?

Comment: And where should the rewrite module take the ID from? Can you answer that?

Comment: @arkascha It looks like the ids are only in the old URLs, so I'd think that the rewrite rule would match them, but not put them in a capturing group because they won't be needed for the redirect.